# What is the most stable flutter version in 2021 and which is the best channel for me

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Which is the most stable flutter version in 2021 that won't popup these kind of error below every-time i try to add a dependence/package... i have tried flutter Upgrade and it didn't even take up-to a day before i had to downgrade because of all the errors i was getting

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.4.
>
> Because another_test depends on uuid >=3.0.0-nullsafety.0 which
> requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed. pub
> get failed (1; Because another_test depends on uuid
>
> > =3.0.0-nullsafety.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.) exit code 1

Then for the Channel I am just new to flutter, i am in the learning process but i am working on a project which i am planning to release so i get confused when it comes to choosing the best channel for me giving that i am still learning and i am building app that i will publish to the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully read the flutter channel note which i will paste below

> Flutter has the following channels, in increasing order of stability:
>
> **master** The current tip-of-tree, absolute latest cutting edge build. Usually functional, though sometimes we accidentally break
> things.
>
> **dev** The latest fully-tested build. Usually functional, but see Bad Builds for a list of known "bad" dev builds. We continually try to
> roll master to dev. Doing so involves running many more tests than
> those that we run during master development, which is why this is not
> actually the same to master.
>
> **beta** Every month, we pick the "best" dev build of the previous month or so, and promote it to beta. These builds have been tested
> with our codelabs.
>
> **stable** When we believe we have a particularly good build, we promote it to the stable channel. We intend to do this more or less
> every quarter, but this may vary. We recommend that you use this
> channel for all production app releases. We may ship hot fixes to the
> stable channel for high-priority bugs, although our intent is to do
> this rarely.

So after reading the above article i believe that the best channel for you is the **stable** Channel and i guess it should also solve your first problem giving that the build has to go through the Master then Dev then Beta before they finally release it to Stable Channel